# Repeat Control Data does not display

Tags: xpages

I have an app that is using one repeat control inside of another repeat control.  The outside control uses a simple DbColumn to capture data from a view column.  I have a computed field to display the list from the repeat control.  The inside Repeat control uses a simple DbLookup based on the list from the outside repeat control.  I display that data using a link.  The issue is, The repeat control that uses the DbLookup will not display the corresponding data from the outside repeat control unless there are a minimum of two documents to display.  If the outside control lists Company A, and there is only one purchase order document associated with Company A, it won't display.  As soon as you create a second document for Company A, both documents display as designed.  This is happening on two separate apps I'm working on.  Is there something I'm doing or NOT doing?

Answer (score 3):

This is because @DbColumn() doesn't return an array if there's only 1 result - instead it returns a string.

I will recommend that you use this improved version of DbColumn and DbLookup that handles this and more - including support for caching:
http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=dblookup-dbcolumn-with-cache-sort-and-unique

Comment: Is there no simpler way to make this work?  That's a boatload of code to return a simple result.

Comment: You could create your own helper method to convert the result of the DbColumn to an array if it's a string. The code snippet I link to is however a great thing to include in your general code library.

Comment: I'm obviously doing something wrong because when I insert the snippet into the repeat control code I get this: Function:[function Function]

Comment: You need to add the code snippet to a script library that you then add as a resource to your XPage. You can then use the DbColumnArray() and DbLookupArray() functions instead of the @DbColumn() and @DbLookup() functions.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I'm assuming I don't have to modify the code at all then?

Comment: Correct. You just replace the DbColumn and DbLookup calls (and can choose to cache the values too)

Comment: Are you pasting the snippet into a script library?

Comment: Go figure.  I tried it again & it accepted the snippet as written.  I'll let you know how it works.

Comment: Snippet is not working.  Is there anything I have to do that is being assumed I know?  Remember, I'm still in the "Larval" stage of experience & knowledge of Xpages and JavaScript, not to mention Function calls.  I noticed the snippet referencing a Scoped variable.  Should I be doing something with that?  I'm grabbing at straws at this point.  @DbColumn works Great but won't display single value lists.  The DbColumnArray function is not working AT ALL for me.  HELP.

Comment: I assume knowledge of script libraries and resources. Please have a look at the Mastering XPages book

Comment: Mark - 
Another option is to not use @DbColumns at all.  Create SSJS functions to get your entries using the domino backend object model similar to LotusScript. If you don't have a comfort zone with XPages I suggest you check out the XPagescheatsheet.com and NotesIn9.com. I have MANY beginning videos there.  Here's an episode guide.  http://www.mindmeister.com/280533435/notesin9

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the @DbLookup / @DbColumn in an @Explode may solve your problem. @Explode should return an array.